# React Native GraphQL nested data array returning error

Tags: react-native, graphql, aws-amplify, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I have tried everything I can think of to solve this and am still stumped. I am using AWS AppSync GraphQL to store a dataset that I would like to call into a SectionList.

For the SectionList I am using a hardcoded id to call the data set through a GraphQL query. The SectionList displays correctly when I am using dummy data. It also displays the 1-to-1 relationships in the API correctly.

I already configured amplify to increase the statement depth and I can see the data in the Object.

**Code for the SectionList**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Image, ImageBackground, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, SectionList, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import { getGame, listGameSections, listGames } from '../graphql/queries';

const Item = ({ title }) => (

    <View>
        <Text>
           {title}
        </Text>
    </View>
);

const GameScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [game, setGame] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchGame = async () => {
            const gameInfo = { id: '0e2cb273-b535-4cf7-ab16-198c44a4991c'};
        if (!gameInfo) {
          return;
        }
            try {
                const response = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getGame, {id: gameInfo.id}))
                setGame(response.data.getGame);
                console.log(response);
            } catch (e) {
            }
        };

        fetchGame();
    }, [])

    return (

        <SafeAreaView>
            <View>
               <Text>
                 {game.name}
               </Text>    
            </View>

            <SectionList
                sections={game.sections.items}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
                renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
                    <View>
                        <Text>{title}</Text>
                    </View>
                )}>
            </SafeAreaView>
)
};

export default GameScreen;
```

**Log of the object.**
I am attempting to display the getGame.sections.items array but am returning an error undefined is not an object. Cannot read property items of undefined.

[image: The Object being called]

Please help, I am so stumped now. When I call game.name earlier in the function it displays correctly, but game.sections.items throws an error in the SectionList that it is undefined.

Comment: it's async then at 1st render state ('game') has initial value `[]` (why array!?) ... then no `game.title` (safely undefined) nor `game.sections.items` (trying to acces subfield of undefined) AT THIS TIME, of course ... follow tutorials more strictly ... there is a reson to display '"loading"

Answer (score 0):

Xadm, you pointed me in the right direction. I added this to my code:

```
const [game, setGame] = useState({});
const [gameSection, setGameSection] = useState([]);
```

and in my useEffect:

```
setGameSection(response.data.getGame.sections.items)
```

When calling the data, game.name wanted an object, while game.sections.items wanted an array for the SectionList. Adding 2 different functions for each initial states, one for the objects and one for the array, was able to fix the problem and render the data.

Comment: this proves you still don't understand ... there is no need to duplicate data into local state .. back to tutorials